# Android SavedPrefrerences loading?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am trying to make an app(http://pastebin.com/uWkP6XNY) that when you press a button, creates a custom sms message. The user can go to a second activity (http://pastebin.com/MK2NPV5R) thats full of edit-texts that when saved, will bring back strings to be used to change the custom sms.

The issues I am facing is how I initalize my variables with whats in savedpreferences. I put this in my onCreate method.

```
smsintroduction = (sp.getString("intro", "")); //these are both strings initalized at the top
 smsbody = (sp.getString("body", ""));
```

On start up, since it can't get "intro" from the dictionary, it goes to a null string. I want to be able to use my save() function in my second activity to save, which I Think I already do, but be able to change my two strings above.

I put the code above to set the strings in a method that completes the finalized textbody, but it keeps giving me emptystrings.
The only thing that gets created is "!", as shown in finishedtext().

Comment: Please add relevant parts of your code here - nobody would read all your classes to find out what's going on. Also format your code better! Avoid empty lines, delete parts that you don't need - don't comment them out - use an IDE like eclipse and hit Ctrl+Shif+F once in a while.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like in your MainActivity in onCreateOptionsMenu you are overriding the sp member previously set in onCreate with

```
sp = getSharedPreferences("prefs", 0);
```

Try removing that line or setting those shared prefs to a different instance member.

Comment: Okay, so I intalize SharedPreferences at the top of the activity. Then  in the onCreate method, set SP = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());? Its still giving me a null string when I edit the texts.

Comment: Updated my answer based on a closer look at the source you provided.

Comment: Ugh. How did I not see that. I don't even know why I have that line. But removing that line still didn't help. I still get just a ! when finishedtext is made.

Comment: I put  Toast.makeText( this, smsintroduction, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); in my finishedtext() method at the top of my main. It should give me something from my sharedpreferences, but its not even opening up the toast... so nothing gets saved properly.